# How to change eval statement to es6 syntax?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, refactoring, eval

I have this function with an eval function, it's working fine evaluating the function defined in the string with the expected 'value', but do not understand why the variable between quotes 'value' is evaluated as parameter to the function instead of the string = value.

```
function evaluateString(value) {
   var funcString = "function validate(input){ return input === \"999999\"; }";

    if (eval("(" + funcString + ")("+'value'+")")){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false
    }
}
```

I've tried this but it always returned false.

```
eval(`(${funcString})('value')`);
```

and this (without quotes)

```
eval(`(${funcString})(value)`);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
eval("(" + funcString + ")("+'value'+")")
```

is equivalent to your second attempt:

```
eval(`(${funcString})(value)`);
```

the only issue is that your

```
var value = "2";
```

essentially overrides whatever the function argument is, so even with the eval fixed your code returns `false`. Just delete that line. That leaves you with

```
function evaluateString(value) {
   var funcString = "function validate(input){ return input === \"999999\"; }";
    if (eval(`(${funcString})(value)`)){
       return true;
    }else{
       return false
    }
}
evaluateString("999999"); // true
evaluateString("99999"); // false
```

Comment: you are all right, thank you. but I still have the issue, the es6 version keeps being null

Comment: @AguV I put a full example in my answer.

Comment: @AguV What doesn't work? If you paste that into a Chrome console it prints true/false just like you asked. If it's not working then you need to elaborate on what isn't working in your question.